# Installing 12.04 on a 14.04

Tags: 12.04, boot, usb

I have Ubuntu 14.04, I want to do a fresh install of 12.04 so I can play dota 2 with the steam client for linux. I have a startup usb ready with 12.04 but when I restart or turn off it goes directly to 14.04 skipping the instalation.

Entering Bios, under boot and I see that usb boot is enabled, but on the list of boot options usb is not there, my device is not listed. Same with f12.

All I need is to be able to boot from that usb, so I can do a fresh install.

I'm using lenovo g780. And im using this ISO http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-i386.iso

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two questions. Are you not able to get Steam running in 14.04 (I have been able to)? Also, how are you putting the ISO on usb? I've always found using dd to be the best method.

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable secure boot and change to legacy boot instead of efi. After this it read the usb without issues.